# The meaning of the Roles in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

Just because I’m confused around this issue I’d like to ask the following questions, and please I would like to receive clear and easy understandable answers. Not deep analyze.

1.What is the Roles for a programmer?
2.What is the role of the Schemas owned by this… which related with them?
3.What is the meaning and the use for Securables in Roles 
4.Why we add Users to a Role?
5.How we may handle the Roles in conjunction with to the Users, inside of a project?

Thank you very much in advance.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

The reason uploading this question based on an issue which I’m facing developing a web.site.
 And the Issue is.
I have a number (100) of Web.Pages and a number (20.000) of Users (application users), each User has a special code, thus numerous Users belong to a Group (regarding to there code) and others in another Group.
Now, when a User of a certain Group tries to open a page I need a rule to look if he has the right to open this page.
For that reason I was thinking to use the Roles… But I steel don’t know if that is a good idea rather to create my own rule between Web.Pages and Application Users…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles are predefined sets of permissions on the database or on the server, that can be granted to the user as a package. Best practice is creating your own set of roles for the database, with the exact permissions that they need.